# How to convert date format on view?

Tags: views, datetime

I have created a View. Its display format is grid.One of field is Time.

It is displayed as "Time: 1300". I need to get it printed as "Time: 1:00 pm".
I am using [Room Reservations](https://www.drupal.org/project/room_reservations) module and in my reservations tab time is displayed.

Can it be done with GUI or code needs any modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert date format in Views, you have to go the settings field which you are added to view. In settings, there is a `Date Format` select list field. You can choose the default time format provided or you can make your  custom date format by selecting the `Custom` from select list. A new textfield will appear "Custom Date Format". In this field, you can make your own custom date format using the link `PHP Manual` link provide in the description of this field.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the date field is used to create the Time field you mentioned.

You need to create new Date format in **yourdomain/admin/config/regional/date-time/formats**, refer the PHP date manual, in  your case it will be (g a).

Followed by create the date type in **yourdomain/admin/config/regional/date-time** and choose the format you created. Then open your views and edit the Time field and choose the Date format what you created earlier as follows,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your global time settings:

admin/config/regional/settings

Otherwise you can check the settings of your field of your contenttype:

admin/structure/types/manage/your_contenttype/fields

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if using the [Views Date Format SQL](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_date_format_sql) module could be a solution for you. Here are some quotes about it (from its project page):

> ... allows to format date fields using SQL.
>
> The core functionality is to remove the date formatting from render() and put it in query(). I.e. format date values using SQL's DATE_FORMAT rather than PHP's format_date.
>   This is achieved by assigning a new default handler to node 'created' and 'changed' date fields. This handler extends and overrides views's build in views_handler_field_date.
>
> The UI is completely unobtrusive, only a single checkbox "Use SQL to format dates" is added to the handler configuration popup.

Your question is not about creating charts in Drupal, but you may want to refer to [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096#comment-7697321) also for an example of how we typically use it within the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module.